# Remove space in PHP that was added using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

My requirement is to add space after comma using JavaScript and that added space should be using
  PHP in order to continue my operation.

### JavaScript:

```
return date.replace(/\,/g ,', ');
```

### PHP Code:

```
$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']);
```

`$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']` variable has the date as its value. Please help me

Comment: In Php javaScript spaces are not removing i.e Does not recognize

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `str_replace`

```
$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt'] = str_replace(", ",",",$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']);
```

Comment: thank you for your ans but php code does not remove javascript space

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace like this

```
$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt'] = str_replace(", ",",",$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']= preg_replace('/( *)/', '',$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my Question is In Controller we have to use Regular Expression like this

```
$reqFilterData['reqFrmDt'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-,s|]/', '', $reqFilterData['reqFrmDt']);
```